# Javascript Setting & Shadowing Properties (The prototype chain)

Tags: javascript

I'm reading Kyle Simpson "this & Object Prototypes" book an everything seemes to be clear until the "Setting & Shadowing Properties" section off the "Prototypes" chaptere where i'm getting lost in the 3 scenarios for the myObject.foo = "bar" assignment and especially the first

1. *If a normal data accessor (see Chapter 3) property named foo is found anywhere higher on the [[Prototype]] chain, and it's not marked as read-only (writable:false) then a new property called foo is added directly to myObject, resulting in a shadowed property.*
2. *If a foo is found higher on the [[Prototype]] chain, but it's marked as read-only (writable:false), then both the setting of that existing property as well as the creation of the shadowed property on myObject are disallowed. If the code is running in strict mode, an error will be thrown. Otherwise, the setting of the property value will silently be ignored. Either way, no shadowing occurs.*
3. *If a foo is found higher on the [[Prototype]] chain and it's a setter (see Chapter 3), then the setter will always be called. No foo will be added to (aka, shadowed on) myObject, nor will the foo setter be redefined.*

And what are the "**data accessor**" mean here

Thanks

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Thanks
I dont understand the first case and also what is the ""normal data accessor"

Comment: Hello Joseph
Can you please tell me which section of Chapter 3 ?

Answer (score 0):

More or less:

1) If any 'foo' is found in the prototypes of myObject and it is not read-only or a setter, it will get overwritten to 'bar' for myObject only.

2) If any 'foo' is found in the prototypes of myObject and it is read-only, 'foo' will stay the same, nothing will get overwritten. If you run in strict mode, you'll get an error.

3) If any 'foo' is found in the prototypes of myObject and it is a setter, that setter method will get called instead of getting overwritten to 'bar'.

Comment: Thanks Shilly
i appreciate your help